# Google Form Link Can't be accessed (/formResponse)

Tags: forms, hyperlink

First of all, sorry asking this question cause it's not about current topic

It's just about google form link that my expectation is I could open url with **/formResponse**

**(Website Behaviour)**

**Request:** When I try enter the link https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1WyFssMa_l1e_es9zSMJsojnqTA2AahmpfWiWknXr_P8/formResponse

**Response:** it will redirected to https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1WyFssMa_l1e_es9zSMJsojnqTA2AahmpfWiWknXr_P8/viewform

**(HTTP Post Behaviour)**

**Request:** (POST to https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1WyFssMa_l1e_es9zSMJsojnqTA2AahmpfWiWknXr_P8/formResponse)

**Response:** get an error like this:
***Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.***

---

Anyone can help how to solve this? I appreciate if you get me out of this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when I used `fetch` from JavaScript

```js
const opts = {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "no-cors",
  redirect: "follow",
  referrer: "no-referrer",
  body: formData
}

fetch(url, opts)
...
```